# MAGMI session_write_close Product Import Error

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magmi

I'm having troubles setting up MAGMI on my site, every time I got to import products I am shown this error:

> Warning: session_start():
>   open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_a80ks0ag182lknvd8bfc052qe6, O_RDWR)
>   failed: Permission denied (13) in /httpdocs/magmi/web/head.php on line
>   6
>
> Warning: session_write_close():
>   open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_a80ks0ag182lknvd8bfc052qe6, O_RDWR)
>   failed: Permission denied (13) in
>   /httpdocs/magmi/web/magmi_import_run.php on line 5 Warning:
>   session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (files). Please
>   verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct
>   (/var/lib/php/session) in /httpdocs/magmi/web/magmi_import_run.php on
>   line 5

And products will then not import either, giving me a message saying "**1 error(s) found**" but not displaying the drop down box when I try to see what error I am getting.

If anyone could shed some light on this I would greatly appreciate it!

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite clear.  The user running Magmi does not have the permission to create sessions to the current `session_save_path` for PHP.

You can address this by reading over the solutions covered in [How can I fix the Permission error when I call session_start()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585086/how-can-i-fix-the-permission-error-when-i-call-session-start)