# Why PHP session files are written by different users depending on pages visited?

Tags: php, session, file-permissions

I have a website using PHP sessions.

PHP could write the session file once. But then when I browse other pages, it rises this error : Warning: session_start(): open(/var/www/clients/client0/web1/tmp/sess_iif14obm0s1be3ie5ua9v433d6, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/myfile.php on line 11

After some investigation I found that some pages create a session file with user:group set as www-data:www-data while homepage create it using web1:client0 (ISP config user/group scheme).

Using code from this answer [How can I fix the Permission error when I call session_start()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585086/how-can-i-fix-the-permission-error-when-i-call-session-start)

```
$processUser = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
print $processUser['name'];
exit;

>> output: web1 for homepage www.mydomain.com/
>> output: www-data for other pages www.mydomain.com/anything.html
```

All pages are redirected to index.php. So when there is no redirection, php execute with user web1 (homepage) and when there is a redirection php execute with user www-data.

Here is the code for redirection in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]

<FilesMatch "^fr$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

URLs are http://www.domain.com/fr/something.html

How could I correct this ?

Comment: How does that redirect work? To me it just looks like it forces how the file will be processed.

Comment: @TomHart : You're right, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You must have defined a virtual host for *domain.com* (and/or *www.domain.com*) that preempts the redirection. And in the virtual host definition, the user is set to *web1*.

[See this page for instance](https://www.howtoforge.com/running-vhosts-under-separate-uids-gids-with-apache2-mpm-itk-on-ubuntu-9.10)

In your vhost config there is probably something like that

```
<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
AssignUserId web1_admin web1
</IfModule>
```

Maybe that rings a bell ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Homepage was using CGI/FastCGI wether other pages was using Apache 2.0 Handler (mod_php I think).

I went to ISPConfig and changed PHP mode to mod_php so all pages are handeled by the same handler.