# PHP: session error

Tags: php, session-variables, superglobals

I don't know how to solve this problem. What should I do?

Here is the error I get:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/tmp/sess_a08ea88dc4be1f7dfa7ab9767ee7d04e, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/a9321792/public_html/results.php on line 2

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585086/how-can-i-fix-the-permission-error-when-i-call-session-start

Comment: The user running the PHP instance doesn't have permission to write to the temporary directory on your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are encountering a permissions violation in the `/tmp/` dir. Make sure php has write access to the directory. If you cannot change the permissions for any reason, look at this documentation on changing your session save path:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

- [Change the session path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) to a writable folder
- Make sure the user PHP runs under can write and create files in /tmp