# Failed session_start()

Tags: php, macos

### Below is my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'includes/database.php';
    require_once 'includes/register-inc.php';

?>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
     <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">HOME</a>
                <li><a href="">LOGIN</a>
                <li><a href="">REGISTER</a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
     </body>
```

---

### The output on Chrome is below:

Warning: session_start(): open(/var/folders/w7/n7vzrtds52g1bc1zv0l_85jc0000gn/T/sess_3cea3e7e9f3c04bfc55ac456e6f65166, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PHPPractice/NEW/includes/header.php on line 2

---

I changed the permission of the "var" folder to read/write on Mac OS but nothing has changed. I don't know what I've missed.
Thanks

Comment: did that answers your question ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585086/how-can-i-fix-the-permission-error-when-i-call-session-start

Comment: Did you change permissions just on folder "var"? You may need to change the permissions again but as Recursive, so all sub folders have matching permissions

Comment: Check the session path in your PHP config and adjust the permissions on that folder to allow the web server to write. SIP will not allow you to "change the permission of the `var` folder to read/write" but do not just blindly adjust permissions on system folders without understanding what you are doing.

Comment: @miken32 Got it!