# PHP Randomly Warning Permission denied (13) on session_start()

Tags: php, session, warnings

I have randomly this issue:

> WARNING: FILE: *[PATH_PROJECT]*\class\session.class.php
> MESSAGE: session_start(): open(*[PATH_SESSION]*\sess_966tkue45v5mm6ftvqgqhnd21r, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)

I write without problem in *[PATH_SESSION]*

For example this issue It shows up 10 times in day and in the other cases working fine.

I use PHP 8.0 on Windows Server.

Comment: Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585086/how-can-i-fix-the-permission-error-when-i-call-session-start)

Comment: "I write without problem in [PATH_SESSION]" - You do, but the web server (Apache, IIS, Nginx...) is most likely not using your user credentials. Are the files in a protected location such as your user home folder?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to change your **session.save_path php.ini** directive

You can do that using **session_save_path**

for more information: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php